# nginx server multiple location reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-location

I have 3 website running in port 8000,8001 and 8002 I want to reverse the request this server . But this not working

```
server {
listen 6102;


    location /app1 {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           }
location /app2 {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           }
location /app3 {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:8002;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
           }


    }
```

it my configuration file . please tell me where I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I usually do is adding the slash (/) at the end of the location. The following snippet is a working config.

```
location /reporting/ {
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```